# How To download a file from webserver to your computer?

Tags: webserver, freebsd, netcat

I'm back connected  with a Freebsd server [netcat ] And There is a File On /tmp That i want to download it but 
Its can't be browsed with My Browser So there is any ways to download it ? 
because i don't have access to others folders . Just /tmp

Comment: Try some free ftp tools and download the files to your computer

Comment: Are you trying to automatically download a file from your server to the computer of those who are browsing to your web server?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [fetch(1)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjq5IfTvNTSAhXIG5AKHVidAywQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.freebsd.org%2Fcgi%2Fman.cgi%3Ffetch(1)&usg=AFQjCNFPxUWTESlYb7mf3QbPX2FjaxiOgQ&sig2=i9aHWqtLBTpB7pdG7ajBiQ)

```
eg. fetch https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
```

or download wget with

```
pkg install wget
```

and use wget

```
eg. wget https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an account on the server and the ssh daemon is running you can use *scp*.  From a terminal emulator (e.g. *xterm*) you can do `% scp freebsd.server.org:/tmp/file .`.  Of course replace *freebsd.server.org* with the correct name of the host.
If you're on windows, you could also use a graphical program such as *Winscp*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH installed on the server, you can use any SSH client out there. For Windows, WinSCP is a good option but if you run *nix OS with Gnome, Nautilus can do the same natively.